# Eclipse formatter to keep One-Liners

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, formatter

Can Eclipse Formatter be configured to keep:

```
public Long getId() { return this.id; }
```

And maybe to format small (one line) definitions as one-liners?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No: [bug 205973](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=205973) has been written to request such a formatter option.
3 years later, it doesn't seem likely to be implemented.

---

Edit May 2001:

[maleki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112607/maleki) mentions, in response to [orbfish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/407502/orbfish)'s comment, that at least you have some control over the zones of code which Eclipse may or *may not* format:

[Java development user guide > Reference > Java Editor > Formatter Help page](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-java-editor-formatter.htm)

This isn't a direct answer, but it can help:

[image: formatter disabling-enabling tags]

Comment: Thanks, not what I was hoping for, but a fair answer.

Comment: Any way to just KEEP IT FROM AUTO-FORMATTING?????  (sorry, just spent another half hour reformatting my code after spending 15-minutes doing what I thought was turning off auto-formatting).

Comment: Really late to this party but you have a bit of control where it formats using tags. http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-java-editor-formatter.htm

Comment: @maleki: good point, I have include that option in the answer. @orbfish: maybe maleki's comment can help?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge (and after a quick look), the default formatter does not provide this level of granularity for customization.  If it's that important to the business, you might be able to find an Eclipse plugin (perhaps commercial) that can be configured with advanced rules like this.