# Can Eclipse CDT formatter be set to keep one liners when reformatting?

Tags: c++, eclipse, coding-style, formatting

In my include files I'll often have some single line functions, such as:

```
void SetValue(int value) {m_value = value;}
int GetValue() const {return m_value;}
```

I like keeping these on one line but sometimes the code gets wonky and I hit the keystroke to auto reformat the file and my normal code style settings break this up into multiple lines, which I like for non-single line functions. I read in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878577/eclipse-formatter-to-keep-one-liners) about a Java @formatter flag so I tried it, but alas, those Java folks get all the cool tricks. Does anyone know if there is an equivalent for the C++ editor, or another way to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to not be possible.  See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2879936/1686657) (not specifically about CDT).